# Build java REST API with cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying build a REST API with cassandra as the database but I am don't see any documentation or examples online, I am using datastax java driver 3.0.0.

```
public class CassandraDBUtil {

private Cluster cluster;
private PoolingOptions options;
private Session session;

public void connect(String node) {
    options = new PoolingOptions(). setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768);
    cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint(node)
            .withAddressTranslator(new EC2MultiRegionAddressTranslator())
            .withPoolingOptions(options)
            .build();
    Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", metadata.getClusterName());
    for (Host host : metadata.getAllHosts()) {
        System.out.printf("Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n", host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(),
                host.getRack());
    }
    session = cluster.connect("dropalletcassdb");
}

public Session getSession(){
    if(this.cluster != null){
        System.out.println("@@@@ Returning an old session");
        return this.session;
    }else{
        System.out.println("@@@ Creating a new session");
        connect("127.0.0.1");
        return this.session;
    }
}
```

Below is a function in another class,

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ActiveBid> getTrackInJSON() {
    logger.info("LoginApi: Returning the active bid");
    Session session = cassDB.getSession();
    String cqlStatement = "select * from active_bid where username='xyz'";
    for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
      System.out.println(row.toString());
    }
    session.close();
    ActiveBid activeBid = new ActiveBid("3d673111-894d-4fcb-84f7-7d027a9a2419", "XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX", "/p/project_id=1367777", 25, new BigInteger("125"), new BigInteger("150"), "2016-06-04 18:32:37");
    List<ActiveBid> activeBidList = new ArrayList<ActiveBid>();
    activeBidList.add(activeBid);
    return activeBidList;
}
```

In the above code, I have the util class that builds the cluster and the session and then I have the getTrackInJSON in another class which get invokes when a request is made to http://localhost:8080/cassExample/rest/get. Every time I invoke the call to /get, it builds the cluster and the session and the average response time is 500ms. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am not even returning the resultset as the response, I am returning a mocked response and its taking so much time. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building from scratch a REST API you can use [stargate open source project](https://stargate.io/).

It can serve REST, GraphQL API over Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Just put static also with all class variables . like following

private static Cluster cluetr;
private static Session session;
.                                                                                   .                                                                            .                                                                             Then create constructor of this class and initialize all class variables . then create one method getSession . in this first check if cluster and session variables are initialized or not if not initialized then create obeject of this class with default constructor so it will initialize all variables and then send back session variable.